# get_category_link() is not showing anything

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom sidebar-wallpaper-sidebar.php with the following codes. Everything is showing perfectly except the links .

```
<div id="wallpaper-categories" class="widget widget_categories">
    <h4 class="widgettitle">Wallpaper Categories</h4>
    <ul>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'type' => 'post' , 'taxonomy' => 'wallpaper' , 'order' => 'ASC' , 'orderby' => 'name' );
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
    ?>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">
            <a title="<?php echo sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ); ?>" href="<?php get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_category_link()` only returns the link, but does not print it. You need to change `<?php get_category_link($category->term_id) ?>` to `<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id) ?>`.

This is also the most likely culprit in most cases where something needs to be printed but isn't, thus a missing `echo` is the first thing you should check in such cases.

Also, try to change `get_category_link($category->term_id)` to `get_category_link($category->cat_ID)`. I see the `get_categories` example in the WP Codex use `term_id`, but the docs for `get_category_link` clearly state that it expects to be passed the category ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`wallpaper`**  make The Taxonomy Name like **`wallpaper_kjdsnjds`** some unique and random, try i hope it's work.

Comment: Please, try to fix how you explained your answer. It does not look understandable. Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).